# INVALID_SESSION_ID

Tags: apex, rest-api, salesforcedx, callout, postman

I was using postman to do a HTTP request to my salesforce playground instance. I provided client Id, Client Secret, Auth Url and Access Token URL and click on get New access token.
After successful login, I took Access token and Instance url from response and then performed post request. After that, when I try to do callout I am getting INVALID_SESSION_ID.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu2Mk.png

I followed this article to ease the Ip restrictions and bunch of other articles but no use.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387018&type=1

Any help is appreciated on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was a while ago, I also was not longer able to login via Postman. It happened, because the feature enhanced domains was activated. Because of that the urls changed. Probably this is the issue also in your case.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced.htm&type=5